# How to give output from one query to next query

Tags: pandas, pymssql

How to give output from one query to the next query

My out  database `mysql_db`, employee table I will get the id's
`select id from the employee`

`df['out']`

```
         id
0        20017
1        20046
2        20047
...        ...
24337    47883
24338    47884
```

get the id from table one and apply on the `mysql_db2` employee table where its present or not

```
select * from employee where id in ('df['out']')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot join the two tables, because they are in different databases, I would manipulate a string with the values of `df['out']` like this:

```
valid_employee_ids = tuple(df['out'])
cmd = f"""
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     employee
   WHERE
     id IN {valid_employee_ids}
"""
```

Which gives you the following string:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  employee
WHERE
  id IN (20046, 20047, 47883, 47884)
```

---

**Note on f-strings:** The string manipulation above uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), which are only available as of Python 3.5. Alternatively, you could also use [`.format()`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#option-2-strformat) like this:

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id IN {}".format(valid_employee_ids)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where that error is coming from.. Is it possible that you forgot the f-string? What do you get when you type `print(cmd)`?

Comment: he might be on Python 2 or an version before `fstrings` maybe add in a `.format` to cover both use-cases?